# php7apache2_4.dll no válido 64 bit Windows 10

Tags: php7, apache2

He estado tratando de instalar Apache 2.4.43 con PHP 7 todo en plataforma 64bit dentro de Windows 10.
No lo he conseguido porque al momento de levantar el servicio Apache me sale el error:

```
Cannot load c:/php/php7apache2_4.dll into server: No se puede encontrar el m\xf3dulo especificado
```

El dll que pide: php7apache2_4.dll no venia con el paquete php que he descargado asi que lo he buscado de otros sitios. He probado con varias versiones pero con ninguna funciona.
En el http.conf se ha incluido:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
LoadModule php7_module "c:/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
PHPIniDir "C:/php"
```

También he instalado el redistribuible visual C++ 2015-2019 con el que se ha compilado el PHP 7.

Ayuda por favor.

El dll que pide, ¿Deberia estar en el paquete de PHP? o donde lo consigo

Comment: Estos son los que recomiendan [usar](https://windows.php.net/downloads/snaps/ostc/69801/vc14/x64/) en el reporte de [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69801) de PHP. ¿Los probaste?

Comment: muchas gracias. ya he intentado con ese dll. Me pregunto si serán las versiones de Apache (2.4.43) y PHP (7.2.30) que no son compatibles.

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente descargaste la version **"VC15 x64 Non Thread Safe"**
prueba descargado **"VC15 x64 Thread Safe"** la cual si contiene el dll *php7apache2_4.dll*

https://windows.php.net/download#php-7.4

Una vez tengas el descomprimido en C:/php no olvides dejar el archivo php.ini-development como php.ini

En Apache/conf/httpd.conf

Debes descomentar

```
# LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Y agregar:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>
```

y al final agregar:

```
  LoadModule php7_module C:/php/php7apache2_4.dll
    <IfModule php7_module>
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
    PHPIniDir "C:/php"
  </IfModule>
```

Luego de reiniciar tu apache, deberia funcionar correctamente.

```
C:\Apache24\bin>httpd -k start
```